# save to and load from not working in java

Tags: java, methods, record, acm-java-libraries

for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong with these codes .. the save to keep overwrite itself and the load from doesn't load the already existing data  .. I have searched for this code but it seems like people use different codes .. please help me end my headache

```
// Write to file
static void writeToFile(Customer c[], int number_of_customers) throws IOException {
    // set up file for output
    // pw used to write to file
    File outputFile = new File("Customers.dat");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

    int i = 0;
    do {
        pw.println(c[i].getName());
        pw.println(c[i].getNumber());
        i++;
    } while (i < number_of_customers);
    pw.println(0);
    pw.println(0);
    pw.close();
}

// Read from file
public static int readFromFile(Customer c[]) throws IOException {
    // set up file for reading
    // br used to read from file
    File inputFile = new File("Customers.dat");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String cus;
    int l = -1;
    // Subtract AND assignment operator, It subtracts right operand from the
    // left operand and assign the result to left operand
    int all_customers = 0;
    do {
        l++;
        c[l] = new Customer();
        c[l].cus_name = br.readLine();
        cus = br.readLine();
        c[l].cus_no = Integer.parseInt(cus);
        all_customers++;

    } while (c[l].cus_no != 0); // end while

    br.close(); // end ReadFile class
    return all_customers - 1;
}
```

Comment: What, exactly is wrong? Your description of the problem is quite vague

Comment: the first code overwrite the data exist in it ie: if the file has a name0 and number0 saved to it ..then you type name2 and number2 the first values will be deleted and the second values will take it's place ...... as for the second code it doesn't read the values that already saved if you don't overwrite it .. i hope it is clear to you

Comment: So you want `writeToFile` to merge the file content with the passed in records?

Comment: i want  .....  the writeToFile() to save the recoreds entered without deleting the old ones like : name0 number0  name2 number2   .. and the readFromFile() to read the old and new entry .. thank u

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues with your code.

Looking first at your `readFromFile` method:

- You're passing in an array that your method is filling up with all the records it finds. What happens if there are more customers in the file than there's room for in the array? (hint: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a thing)
- You're parsing an integer read as a string from the file. What happens if the file is corrupt and the line read is not an integer?
- The name of the file to read from is hard-coded. This should be a constant or configuration option. For the purpose of writing methods, it is best to make it a parameter.
- You're opening the file and reading from it in the method. For purposes of unit testing, you should split this into separate methods.
- In general, you should be using a `Collections` class instead of an array to hold a list of objects.
- You're accessing the `Customer` attributes directly in the `readFromFile` method. You should be using an accessor method.

## `Collections`-based approach

Here's my proposed rewrite based on using `Collections` APIs:

```
public static List<Customer> readFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    // set up file for reading
    // br used to read from file
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    List<Customer> customers = readFromStream(br);

    br.close(); // end ReadFile class

    return customers;
}
```

This uses this method to actually read the contents:

```
public static List<Customer> readFromStream(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {

    List<Customer> customerList = new LinkedList<>();

    // Subtract AND assignment operator, It subtracts right operand from the
    // left operand and assign the result to left operand
    boolean moreCustomers = true;
    while (moreCustomers) {
        try {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setName(br.readLine());
            String sCustNo = br.readLine();
            customer.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(sCustNo));
            if (customer.getNumber() == 0) {
                moreCustomers = false;
            }
            else {
                customerList.add(customer);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            // happens if the line is not a number.
            // handle this somehow, e.g. by ignoring, logging, or stopping execution
            // for now, we just stop reading
            moreCustomers = false;
        }
    }

    return customerList;
}
```

Using a similar approach for `writeToFile`, we get:

```
static void writeToFile(Collection<Customer> customers, String filename) throws IOException {
    // set up file for output
    // pw used to write to file
    File outputFile = new File(filename);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

    writeToStream(customers, pw);

    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}

static void writeToStream(Collection<Customer> customers, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException {

    for (Customer customer: customers) {
        pw.println(customer.getName());
        pw.println(customer.getNumber());
    }
    pw.println(0);
    pw.println(0);

}
```

However, we still haven't addressed your main concern. It seems you want to merge the file content with the customers in memory when you call `writeToFile`. I suggest that you instead introduce a new method for this purpose. This keeps the existing methods simpler:

```
static void syncToFile(Collection<Customer> customers, String filename) throws IOException {

    // get a list of existing customers
    List<Customer> customersInFile = readFromFile(filename);

    // use a set to merge
    Set<Customer> customersToWrite = new HashSet<>();

    // first add current in-memory cutomers
    customersToWrite.addAll(customers);

    // then add the ones from the file. Duplicates will be ignored
    customersToWrite.addAll(customersInFile);

    // then save the merged set
    writeToFile(customersToWrite, filename);
}
```

Oh... I almost forgot: The magic of using a `Set` to merge the file and in-memory list relies on you to implement the `equals()` method in the `Customer` class. If you overwrite `equals()`, you should also overwrite `hashCode()`. For example:

```
public class Customer {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj != null) && (obj instanceof Customer) && (getNumber() == ((Customer)obj).getNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getNumber()+31;
    }
};
```

## `CustomerList`-based approach

If you cannot use `Collections` APIs, the second-best would be to write your own collection type that supports the same operations, but is backed by an array (or linked list, if you have learned that). In your case, it would be a list of customers. I'll call the type `CustomerList`:

Analyzing our existing code, we'll need a class that implements an `add` method and a way to traverse the list. Ignoring `Iterators`, we'll accomplish the latter with a `getLength` and a `getCustomer` (by index). For the synchronization, we also need a way to check if a customer is in the list, so we'll add a `contains` method:

```
public class CustomerList {

    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 100;
    private static final int SIZE_INCREMENT = 100;

    // list of customers. We're keeping it packed, so there
    // should be no holes!
    private Customer[] customers = new Customer[INITIAL_SIZE];
    private int numberOfCustomers = 0;

    /**
     * Adds a new customer at end. Allows duplicates.
     * 
     * @param newCustomer the new customer to add
     * @return the updated number of customers in the list
     */
    public int add(Customer newCustomer) {

        if (numberOfCustomers == customers.length) {
            // the current array is full, make a new one with more headroom
            Customer[] newCustomerList = new Customer[customers.length+SIZE_INCREMENT];
            for (int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                newCustomerList[i] = customers[i];
            }
            // we will add the new customer at end!
            newCustomerList[numberOfCustomers] = newCustomer;

            // replace the customer list with the new one
            customers = newCustomerList;
        }
        else {
            customers[numberOfCustomers] = newCustomer;
        }

        // we've added a new customer!
        numberOfCustomers++;

        return numberOfCustomers;
    }

    /**
     * @return the number of customers in this list
     */
    public int getLength() {
        return numberOfCustomers;
    }

    /**
     * @param i the index of the customer to retrieve
     * @return Customer at index <code>i</code> of this list (zero-based).
     */
    public Customer getCustomer(int i) {
        //TODO: Add boundary check of i (0 <= i < numberOfCustomers)
        return customers[i];
    }

    /**
     * Check if a customer with the same number as the one given exists in this list
     * @param customer the customer to check for (will use customer.getNumber() to check against list)
     * @return <code>true</code> if the customer is found. <code>false</code> otherwise.
     */
    public boolean contains(Customer customer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCustomers; i++) {
            if (customers[i].getNumber() == customer.getNumber()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // if we got here, it means we didn't find the customer
        return false;
    }

}
```

With this implemented, the rewrite of the `writeToFile` method is exactly the same, except we use `CustomerList` instead of `List<Customer>`:

```
static void writeToFile(CustomerList customers, String filename) throws IOException {
    // set up file for output
    // pw used to write to file
    File outputFile = new File(filename);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

    writeToStream(customers, pw);

    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

The `writeToStream` is also very similar, except since we're not using an `Iterator`, we have to traverse the list manually:

```
static void writeToStream(CustomerList customers, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < customers.getLength(); i++) {
        pw.println(customers.getCustomer(i).getName());
        pw.println(customers.getCustomer(i).getNumber());
    }
    pw.println(0);
    pw.println(0);

}
```

Similar for `readFromFile` -- pretty much the same except for the list type:

```
public static CustomerList readFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    // set up file for reading
    // br used to read from file
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    CustomerList customers = readFromStream(br);

    br.close(); // end ReadFile class

    return customers;
}
```

The `readFromStream` is also pretty much the same, except for the type (the methods used on `CustomerList` has the same signature as the ones used on `List<Customer>`:

```
public static CustomerList readFromStream(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {

    CustomerList customerList = new CustomerList();

    // Subtract AND assignment operator, It subtracts right operand from the
    // left operand and assign the result to left operand
    boolean moreCustomers = true;
    while (moreCustomers) {
        try {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setName(br.readLine());
            String sCustNo = br.readLine();
            customer.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(sCustNo));
            if (customer.getNumber() == 0) {
                moreCustomers = false;
            }
            else {
                customerList.add(customer);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            // happens if the line is not a number.
            // handle this somehow, e.g. by ignoring, logging, or stopping execution
            // for now, we just stop reading
            moreCustomers = false;
        }
    }

    return customerList;
}
```

The most different method is the `syncToFile`, as we don't have the `Set` type that guarantees no duplicates, we have to manually check each time we try to insert a customer from the file:

```
static void syncToFile(CustomerList customers, String filename) throws IOException {

    // get a list of existing customers
    CustomerList customersInFile = readFromFile(filename);

    // use a set to merge
    CustomerList customersToWrite = new CustomerList();

    // first add current in-memory customers
    for (int i = 0; i < customers.getLength(); i++) {
        customersToWrite.add(customers.getCustomer(i));
    }

    // then add the ones from the file. But skip duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < customersInFile.getLength(); i++) {
        if (!customersToWrite.contains(customersInFile.getCustomer(i))) {
            customersToWrite.add(customersInFile.getCustomer(i));
        }
    }

    // then save the merged set
    writeToFile(customersToWrite, filename);
}
```

Something to note here is that we could have optimized the `add` operations by having an extra constructor for `CustomerList` that took the new capacity, but I'll leave at least *something* for you to figure out ;)

Comment: thank you so much for your input .. it shows true understanding to java where you can make sense of it and helping me to understand it better...the problem with set is that i can't use it since we didn't cover it in my course .. as for the list  i had the following code to show the list                                                    public static void list_of_customers(Customer c[],int number_of_customers)throws IOException
 {
 int m = 0;
 do
 {
 c[m].output();
 m++;
 }while(m<number_of_customers);

 }

Comment: So you had a large array that was guaranteed to have enough space for all customers? Is there a reason why you didn't create a CustomerList type to encapsulate the array management?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, showing how you could do the same without using the `Collections` API.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to fix your write method would be to use a FileOutputStream constructor that lets you request that data be appended to the end of the file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
```

This does assume that you always write a complete final record with an end of line after it, even under error conditions.  You'll still have to deal with this type of situation with the other solution (read and merge), but with that one the subsequent run can detect and deal with it if necessary.  So the append solution I describe is not as robust.

Comment: This is one approach. However, it ignores the fact that we're using a special EOF `Customer` marker (with name and number set to `0`. Of course, we could change the original approach to not use this marker and instead check for EOF using the built-in Java file I/O APIs...